# How can i detect in which devices my iphone application doesn't work?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ios8.1, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Some users wrote bad comment for my iphone application that says "your application crashed when I start your it". But they didn't say any thing about which iphone devides, which ios version etc. I also didn't get crash report on itunesconnect. it couldn't produce ant error report.

My application works fine many devices and whole simulator that iphone 6 and plus included. I can't find in which devices my iphone application doesn't work. I don't have iphone 6, and xcode doesn't support iphone 6 ios 8.1.2 (xcode include only only 8.1 simulator), maybe error in ios 8.1.2 iphone 6, **how can i detect?**

Comment: It's about the problem between your previous release and your recent release?

Comment: Yes, I translated 32bit to 64bit. But I saw that xcode shows many warnings. Are warnings important for this crash? For instance deprecated warnings, plain style unspupported warnings, unused variables warnings, etc

Comment: No, I am talking about your application. Not the architecture.

Comment: what does the crash log (in iTunes) say?